# ipython version mismatches python version in docker

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, dockerfile

I'm building a docker with the following `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
RUN                               \
apt-get update -y              && \
apt-get install python3.8 -y   && \ <----- I ask for python3.8
apt-get install python3-pip -y && \
pip3 install ipython
```

When I ran the image I was surprised to see that the version of `ipython` is `3.6.9`:

```
$ docker build --tag versions --file .\Dockerfile.txt .
$ docker run -d -t --name ver versions
ba9bd772bc6d247a6c83f2bf932a6c5172c23f00e1e6a35f14878608d0f35f89
$ docker exec -it ver bash
# ipython
Python 3.6.9 (default, Jan 26 2021, 15:33:00)
```

Comment: If you have a strong preference about the Python version, maybe you should look at using the python:3.8 image. You can still use apt-get and pip to install more software. More info here: https://hub.docker.com/_/python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package [`python3-pip`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/python3-pip) depends on python3, and the [default python3 for ubuntu 18.04 is version 3.6](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/python3).

There are at least three options.

### Use a python base image

The official `python` base images include `pip`. If possible, I would use one of these.

- `python:3.8` - includes compilers to install compiled packages
- `python:3.8-slim` - does not include compilers

### Install pip with the get-pip.py script

One can install `pip` without the system package manager, for example with the script `get-pip.py`:

```
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
python3.8 get-pip.py
```

### Use ubuntu 20.04

As [@NickODell comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70175105/ipython-version-mismatches-python-version-in-docker/70175137#comment124051084_70175137), ubuntu 20.04 uses 3.8 as the default python. But you will have less fine-grained control over the python version than if you use one of the official python docker images.

Comment: oh I see ... any way to explicitly install ipython3.8 ?

Comment: @OrenIshShalom If you change the base image to Ubuntu 20.04, that has Python 3.8. Or you can use a Python base image; those let you choose the version of Python.